# InstanceAgent::Plugins::C odeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Lifecycle event ApplicationXXXX is a noop

Tags: aws-code-deploy

**What am I doing?**

Using `codedeploy` to deploy the application in ec2.

```
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/xxx-api
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
permissions:
  - object: /home/ec2-user/xxx-api/zarf/aws/application_stop.sh
    mode: 777
    pattern: "**"
    type:
      - file

hook:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: /home/ec2-user/xxx-api/zarf/aws/application_stop.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ec2-user
```

We know the code is being pulled over from `s3`. When I ssh into the ec2, I could see the newest update.

**What is the problem**

It seems like the hooks are not being run. When I access the log, I see the following error:

```
InstanceAgent::Plugins::C odeDeployPlugin::CommandExecutor: Lifecycle event ApplicationXXXX is a noop
```

The codedeploy completes successfully without running any of the scripts.

**What have I tried**

1. I sshed into the ec2, and made sure all the script can be ran with the same permission and user
2. I made sure ec2 had the correct role
3. I made sure the files are being updated